# How come AWS S3 is erasing my extension from PDF files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pdf, amazon-s3

In my current app, I've successfully been able to upload PDFs to my storage.  The problem is, when I download the file, it doesn't have an extension and cannot be opened.  I have to add .pdf to the end of the file for it to be recognized (and it does open the correct file).

However in my app, my file already has a .pdf extension, and I know is uploading properly because I'm able to download and open.

```
  { fieldname: ‘files’,
  originalname: ‘tsunami_zone_e_final.pdf’,
  encoding: ‘7bit’,
  mimetype: ‘application/pdf’,
  size: 2310366,
  bucket: ‘company-name-dev’,
  key: ‘123456789999’,
  acl: ‘public-read’,
  contentType: ‘application/octet-stream’,
  contentDisposition: null,
  storageClass: ‘STANDARD’,
  serverSideEncryption: null,
  metadata: [Object],
  location: ‘https://company-name.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1521233750192',
  etag: ‘“12345etag12345etag12345”’ } ] }
```

Here I logged the file after it's been uploaded to S3 storage. In this example the file would be downloaded as 1521233750192 with no file extension if I were to click on that link right now.

Comment: Either you are uploading it without including .pdf in the name, or your downloading script is not including .pdf in the name.  Check the bucket with a viewer like Cloudberry to see if the upload code is incorrect.  Please also read [tour] then [ask] then [mcve] then edit your question to include your code.  Be careful NOT to include your actual AWS credentials!

Comment: It looks like your client uploaded the PDF to s3://company-name/1521233750192 with content-type application/octet-stream.

Comment: @jarmod do I have to change the content-type?

Comment: If you want a browser to handle the content properly then you should set the appropriate content-type. If you want the downloadable filename to have a .pdf suffix then you should set the S3 object key accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what language/framework you are using but you should make sure to pass the correct `Content-Type` header. You will also need `Content-Disposition` header to make sure your file is downloaded with the same `originalname` property value. And once most browsers will allow for inline display of pdfs, you may also want to force the download (also using `Content-Disposition`). Here is an example with the nodejs S3 sdk.

```
var params = {
  Body: <Binary String>, 
  Bucket: "youbucket", 
  Key: "1521233750192", 
  ContentDisposition: 'attachment; filename="tsunami_zone_e_final.pdf";', // from `originalname`
  ContentType: 'application/pdf', // from `mimetype`
 };

 s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response
 });
```

`Content-Disposition` values can be either `inline` (default value, indicating it can be display inside the Web page, or as the Web page) or `attachment` (indicating it should be downloaded; most browsers presenting a 'Save as' dialog, prefilled with the value of the filename parameters if present).`